# How do I fix TypeError: books.map is not a function that my code generates?

Tags: reactjs

I am developing a livesearch engine using reactJS and getting results from an API link. I encounter an error on compilation saying  
`TypeError: books.map is not a function`

```
export function Books() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [bookName, setbookName] = React.useState('');

  const [query, setQuery] = React.useState('');

  const [books, getBooks] = React.useState('');

  const bookList = books.map((book) => (
      <li key={book.title}>{book.title}</li>
  ));


  const handleChange = e => {
    setbookName(e.target.value);
    setQuery(e.target.vale);
  }

  const search = query => {
    const url = `https://api.itbook.store/1.0/search/${query}`;
    const token = {};
    this.token = token;

    fetch(url)
      .then(results => results.json())
      .then(data => {
        if (this.token === token) {
          getBooks(data.results);
        }
      });
  };

  React.useEffect(()=>{
    search = "";
  });


  return(
    <Paper className={classes.root}>

      <Container maxWidth="lg">

        <form className={classes.container} encType="multipart/form-data">

          <TextField
            required
            id="standard-required"
            placeholder="Enter Book Name"
            label="Search for a Book"
            name="bookName"
            value={bookName}
            onChange={handleChange}
            className={classes.textField}
            multiline
            rowsMax="2"
          margin="normal"/>

          <ul>{bookList}</ul>

        </form>

      </Container>

    </Paper>
  );
}
```

Why does it produce that error ?
I wish to correct the generated error that the code produces & be able to carry out the live search

I have been working with the following code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have initially set `books` to an empty string.

```
const [books, getBooks] = React.useState('');
```

Change to array.

```
const [books, getBooks] = React.useState([]);
```

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is an array method. So when you set initial state of `books` as string you will get the error.